# Access Denied when redirecting to alternate view

Tags: 7, views

I've designed a view that shows a table of data.  Within the global header, I've written

> Click [here](http://www.xxxxx.xxx/xxx/?q=someviewname) to
>   see your events in a calendar
>   format.

The intent is to redirect to another view if the user clicks the link(s).  This works correctly if the user is using Chrome or IE as a browser.  However, if FireFox (on Windows), or, Safari (on Mac), are used, the user gets:

> Access Denied You are not authorized to access this page.

And, they are asked to login again.  I've checked permissions and everything seems to be in order.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please check if cookie & javascript is enabled on the test machines for Mozilla & Safari browser

Comment: @VishalPatil Enabling cookies seems to have resolved this problem.  I will accept if you write this as an answer.

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if cookie & javascript is enabled on the test machines for Mozilla & Safari browser.